# Pandas DataFrame Groupby: How to count the number of grouped rows meeting a condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group rows by 'Age', and return a count of 1) how many rows make up each group, and 2) how many of those rows meet a condition.

Given a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    Age     Died
0   26      0
1   26      0
2   27      1
3   28      0
4   28      1
5   28      1
```

I want to return a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   Age     Count    Died_Count
   26        2        0
   27        1        1
   28        3        2
```

I have tried numerous combinations of various `groupbys` such as  `groupby(['Age', 'Died'])` with different aggregators (`sum`,`count`) but can't seem to find a winning combination. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use namedagg:

```
(
    df.groupby('Age')
    .agg(Count=('Died', 'size'),
        Died_count=('Died', 'sum'))
    .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm...how can I adapt this given that the values in the 'Died' column are dtype 'categorical'?

Comment: If it's categorical, you probably can't use sum. How would you like to aggregate?

Answer (score 2):

Assume your dataframe is `df`

```
res=df.groupby("Age").agg({'Age': 'count', 'Died': 'sum'}).rename(columns={"Age":"Count"})
```

output

```
        Count  Died
Age             
26       2     0
27       1     1
28       3     2
```

you can reset index and set Age to a column as well.

```
res = res.reset_index(drop=False)
```

output

```
   Age  Count  Died
0   26      2     0
1   27      1     1
2   28      3     2
```